# Make computer shutdown if battery < 50%

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, shutdown

My original Dell battery died after one year, and I made the mistake of buying a new one from eBay.

The new battery starts from 100% charged and after 5 minutes drops abruptly from 95% to ~9-10%. Sometimes the computer doesn't even have the time to shutdown safely because it remains without enough power (and because of this I recently had to repair my Windows setup)...

So until I get a new battery, how can I force Windows to shut down automatically if battery reports less than 50% charge?

Comment: Since the battery can only handle a few minutes, wouldn't it be safer to just keep the machine plugged in all the time?

Comment: Yes I'm doing this whenever I can (I can't even do anything on battery because it lasts only for a few minutes). But sometimes there are power outages in my area, and if I'm not around to turn it off, the computer switches to battery...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Control Panel > Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings

Then expand the Battery > Low Battery options

Answer (score 5):

You can set that in Control Panel.

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Go to -> **Power Options** -> Under the current selected Power Plan (e.g. **Balanced**), select **Change Power Settings**.
3. Click **Change advanced power settings**.
4. Under **Battery**, expand **Low Battery level**. In **On battery**, set the value to 50%.
5. Under **Battery**, expand **Critical Battery action**, In **On battery**, verify it is set to **Hibernate** your PC. Else set it to **Shutdown** if you like.